# Form containing two lines in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to print a form on two different lines. So here is what I've done: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/107520/

The issue remains, I have two lines if the screen is reduced, but if the datas can all be printed in the same line then they are all printed in this same line.

I would like to get 2 differents lines (form-row in my sample) all the time.

Have you an idea ? Thanks
There might be some weird stuff coming from bootstrap 2 in this code. If will appreciate you notice it.

```
   <form class="form-inline" name="formFiltre" id="formFiltre" method="post">


            <div class="form-row">
                <input type="hidden" name="nav" value="1" />

                <label for="rf_numero">Numéro</label>
                <input type="text" name="rf_numero" id="rf_numero" class="form-control" value="" />
                <label for="rf_client">Client</label>
                <input type="text" name="rf_client" id="rf_client" class="form-control" value="" />


            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="statuts">Statut </label>
                <select name="rf_statut_commande" id="rf_statut_commande" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">-- Commande --</option>
                    <option value="En attente de paiement" >En attente de paiement</option>
                    <option value="Paiement effectué" >Paiement effectué</option>
                    <option value="Traitement en cours" >Traitement en cours</option>
                    <option value="Expedié" >Expediée</option>
                    <option value="Terminée" >Terminée</option>
                    <option value="Annulée" >Annulée</option>
                </select>
                <select name="rf_reglement_statut" id="rf_reglement_statut" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">-- Règlement --</option>
                    <option value="En attente" >En attente</option>
                    <option value="Effectué" >Effectué</option>
                    <option value="Annulé" >Annulé</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Rechercher" />
            </div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is "mobile first" which means components are "responsive" with Mobile devices given primary consideration. As you reduce screen width, eventually most everything will stack.  You can choose media query "breaks" to control stacking on smaller screen sizes to an extent.

But regarding Inline forms specifically, per Bootstrap Docs:

> - Controls **only appear inline in viewports that are at least 576px wide** to account for narrow viewports on mobile devices.

For your needs you have to pick a form layout that actually defines 2 rows.  The smaller you resize the screen the form will eventually stack all the inputs and so they will *appear* as one column but stacked with consideration to the defined rows.

Bootstrap gives you several *row* options, so if you want an inline form to remain inline instead of stacking you may want to consider conserving row space by making use of `.sr-only` and `placeholder` attributes

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<form name="formFiltre" id="formFiltre" method="post">
  <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <input type="hidden" name="nav" value="1" />
      <label for="rf_numero" class="col-form-label sr-only">Numéro</label>
      <input type="text" name="rf_numero" id="rf_numero" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Numéro" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="rf_client" class="form-label sr-only">Client</label>
      <input type="text" name="rf_client" id="rf_client" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="Client" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="statuts" class="col-form-label sr-only">Statut</label>
      <select name="rf_statut_commande" id="rf_statut_commande" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2">
        <option value="">-- Commande --</option>
        <option value="En attente de paiement">En attente de paiement</option>
        <option value="Paiement effectué">Paiement effectué</option>
        <option value="Traitement en cours">Traitement en cours</option>
        <option value="Expedié">Expediée</option>
        <option value="Terminée">Terminée</option>
        <option value="Annulée">Annulée</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="rf_reglement_statut" id="rf_reglement_statut" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2">
        <option value="">-- Règlement --</option>
        <option value="En attente">En attente</option>
        <option value="Effectué">Effectué</option>
        <option value="Annulé">Annulé</option>
      </select>
      <div class="mb-2 mr-sm-2">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Rechercher" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like sr-only is removing the label and I don't want too, but removing the sr-only seems to give me what I wanted.

Comment: yes it does, as I said, in lieu of a label you can use the `placeholder` attribute on the  `<input>` tag to conserve row space and prevent/delay media query breakpoint wrapping as the row is shorter. But if you found a solution, great. Happy coding!